# Is it ok to have unused Components in project?

Tags: java, dependency-injection

Generally unused/dead code is bad but I wonder what to do with unused components.
Imagine that I have application that sends notifications to users, it sends EmailNotification but after some time we switch to sending notifications with SMS. Instead of deleting EmailNotification class i create interface let's say Notification and I have such structure:

```
Notification
--SmsNotification
--EmailNotification
```

I don't want to remove EmailNotification, because after some time we can go back to EmailNotifications and this change will be as easy as mark EmailNotification class as @Primary.
In such case one of the implementations is always dead code and I wonder if it is ok or generally how to deal with that?

Comment: This is not a dead code, this is an unused code, unless you have this in a same method with a condition on a constant boolean to send one or another. I would not bother to clean those unused class, like you said, you could use it in the future (like using a preference to allow both notification based on used preferences)

Comment: If you don't want the code no-test and sustain to potential bug after some future modification, you may introduce a unit test to include both sub class in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this is not the best practice. 
Instead of this practice, you can separate your code into two different modules, one per component. By this way you can utilize any of two modules depending on your needs through your build automation tool (maven or gradle for example). So the produced jars will contain no dead code.

Answer (score 2):

I would agree that this is not dead code, just unused code. However the code in production should be as clean as possible and so if using version control such as git, I would remove the code as it will always be there in the history of the git repository. If you do not want to do this, then I would suggest a way of explaining why the code is there, some thing like a java doc or readme file.

Answer (score 1):

There should not be any problem in keeping the old code, which might become reusable in future. As a matter of fact, the design itself should be so that it can accommodate changes in components without severe impacts. 
But if there is an unreachable block of code, which certainly will not add any value to the product in present or future, it will be better removed, because it will unnecessarily increase the number of lines of code and will slow down the process of testing, ultimately impacting the delivery. Additionally, this unused code block will also appear in the final product (the JAR/WAR) unwantedly increasing its size.

In my case, I was using SonarQube for static code analysis and there were blocks of code, methods and sometimes files which will show up only at the time of testing. It was slowing down the process as well as taking otherwise unnecessary heap space. Getting rid of those blocks certainly helped us speed up the process.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you should be aware of is that even unused components need to be maintained. Some examples that come to my mind:

- If the `Notification` interface changes, `EmailNotification` has to be changed too
- If you update dependencies used by multiple components, you by might need change `EmailNotification` too
- If you change or introduce new quality measures (e.g. x% of code coverage, specific code styles, no warnings policy etc.), they also apply to unused components - which leads to additional work

The changes required to maintain unused components could be obvious (because it does not compile any more) or subtly (they still compile but since they are not used, no one notices that they fail at runtime). Even if compile errors get fixed, chances are that they are not getting tested properly.

So by keeping unused modules you might have to do more work than necessary for certain changes and you still run the risk of having a broken module that you can't just turn on when needed. It *could* easier to just retire the component and revive and update it when it is actually needed. You could wait with the retirement until there actually is a breaking change though. If you are lucky, no breaking change comes before the component is needed again.

If you are certain that you'll need the component again in near future, then keep it. But make sure to maintain it properly.